::before selector doesnt work on I element
I'm trying to apply a ::before pseudo selector to an i element that uses fontawesome theming. However, the ::before css overlaps the Icon (or rather, the icon itself disappears) when I select it using its parent.
This only happens if there's a class selector anywhere in it's path: .foo a i::before {}; doesnt work;
a i::before {} works fine.
Unfunctional CSS:


.foo i {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: 5;
}
.foo i::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2em;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -5;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="" class="foo">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>



Changing the z-index doesn't do anything either.
The only way It works is If I just select the i element directly.
Here's a working example of the result im trying to achieve:


i {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: 5;
}
i::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2em;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -5;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="" class="foo">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>




This is an issue of specificity. If you inspect the pseudo element in your first example using your browser dev tools, you will see that a rule with the selector .fa-chevron-right:before tries to apply content: "\f054";, but it is crossed out - because your rule .foo i::before has higher specificity, and sets content: '';. But of course you don't need to resolve the specificity problem here, you simply need to stop setting content: ''; in your own rule in the first place.

Okay, wow. That worked! Thanks. I'll keep specificity in mind more often.

This is a specificity issue.
Your :before declaration is overriding the one provided by FontAwesome to create the icon. You don't need to re-state the :before, just add additional styles.
position and z-indez are also superflous.


.foo i {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.foo i::before {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="" class="foo">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>



